# How to construct a Date from a String

Tags: java, android, datetime, date

I have to compare two dates in if/else, the current date and the predefined date (let's say 1 Jan 2011). This was supposed to be simple, but I can't find the way to set the predefined date something like:

```
Java.util.Date date = new Date("2011-01-01");
```

How to compare two dates? I really don't know why it's so complicated to do.

Comment: [Compare two dates in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3144387/compare-two-dates-in-java)

Comment: @Jonathon: I don't think so. The OP here wants to know how to construct the predefined date.

Comment: Agreed, too hasty on my part.  I would retract if I could and simply link to it since it's still useful and relevant.

Comment: `Date` objects have the `after(...)` and `before(...)` methods. The current date can be obtained by just creating a `new Date()`. To get a date from String, use `SimpleDateFormat`. Else use the calendar method like Matt Ball mentions.

Comment: Modern approach: `java.time.LocalDate.parse( "2011-01-01" ).isBefore( LocalDate.now() )`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

...

Date today = new Date();
Date predefined = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse("2011-01-01");

if(today.equals(predefined)) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Here's the format string reference: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Answer (score 7):

Use [`java.util.Calendar`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html).

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.clear();
cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2011);
cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
cal.set(Calendar.DATE, 1);
Date predefined = cal.getTime();

Date now = new Date();

if (now.after(predefined))
{
    // do something
}
else
{
    // do something else
}
```

or use [JodaTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/).

> How to compare two dates? I really don't know why it's so complicated to do.

Because calendars/dates/times are really hard to get right, and the Java implementation of `Date` (and, in part `Calendar`) is an utter train wreck.

Comment: Thanks very much for such detailed reply. I learned from it. However, I myself thought of doing it via `Calendar` object, but I fing it's much simpler to do it via `SimpleDateFormat` object. I've already tried with the same object in my code, but I did not use the `parse()` method. I will add plus to your reply, but I will mark the upper one as the answer.

Comment: @askmo: no problem. Just an FYI, another good option with `DateFormat` is using the static factory methods, like `DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT).format(...)`

Comment: Thanks. I am aware of that method, but my problem was because I did not use the `parse()` method.

Comment: @askmo: yes, my apologies - I meant `DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT).parse(...)` not `...format(...)`!

Answer (score 3):

date.CompareTo(someOtherDate);

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#compareTo(java.util.Date)

Comment: This does not solve the comparison with a predefined date