# Compare dates using Calendar class using java

Tags: java

The user entered date is using a drop down separately for day, month and year. I have to compare the user entered date with today's date and check if it is same day or future day. I am a bit confused about the time portion because I am not interested in time, just the date. How to solve this without using the Date class (I read it is not recommended to use Date class).

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Compare two dates in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3144387/compare-two-dates-in-java)

Answer (score 12):

You first need to create `GregorianCalendar` instance representing entered date:

```
Calendar user = new GregorianCalendar(2012, Calendar.MAY, 17);
```

And one for "now":

```
Calendar now = new GregorianCalendar();
```

This will yield positive value if date is in the future and negative - if in the past:

```
user.compareTo(now);
```

Few notes about constructing `user` object:

- it uses current JVM time zone, so in my case it is midnight, 17th of May in CEST time zone
- be careful with months, they are 0-based

Comment: +1 Interesting, I didn't know compareTo would do that. Great Answer!

Answer (score 2):

Try class DateUtils of library Apache Commons Lang.

This class provides the method truncatedEquals(cal1, cal2, field).

So you can check for equality with a single line of code:

```
Calendar user = new GregorianCalendar(2012, Calendar.MAY, 17);
Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();

if(DateUtils.truncatedEquals(user, now, Calendar.DATE)){
    // your code goes here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple calculation :

```
GregorianCalendar gc1 = new GregorianCalendar();
GregorianCalendar gc2 = new GregorianCalendar();
gc2.add(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 2); // gc2 is 2 days after gc1
long duration = (gc2.getTimeInMillis() - gc1.getTimeInMillis() )
                         / ( 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24) ;
System.out.println(duration);
```

-> 2

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution:

```
    int day = 0; //user provided
    int month = 0; //user provided
    int year = 0; //user provided
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MONDAY, month);
    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day);
    long millisUser = calendar.getTime().getTime();
    long nowMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();
    if(nowMillis < millisUser) {
        ...
    }
```

Above is check if date is in future.

There is nothing wrong in using `java.util.Date`
You can use:

```
    int day = 0; //user provided
    int month = 0; //user provided
    int year = 0; //user provided
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MONDAY, month);
    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day);
    Date userSubmit = calendar.getTime();
    Date now = new Date();
    if(userSubmit.after(now)) {
        ...
    }
```

But if you want fluent, easy and intuitive API with dates I recommend using [JodaTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 0):

Use a gregorian calendar. 
If you wanted to know the number of days difference between two dates then you could make a method similar to the following.

```
  public int getDays(GregorianCalendar g1, GregorianCalendar g2) {
  int elapsed = 0;
  GregorianCalendar gc1, gc2;
  if (g2.after(g1)) {
     gc2 = (GregorianCalendar) g2.clone();
     gc1 = (GregorianCalendar) g1.clone();
  }
  else   {
     gc2 = (GregorianCalendar) g1.clone();
     gc1 = (GregorianCalendar) g2.clone();
  }
  gc1.clear(Calendar.MILLISECOND);
  gc1.clear(Calendar.SECOND);
  gc1.clear(Calendar.MINUTE);
  gc1.clear(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
  gc2.clear(Calendar.MILLISECOND);
  gc2.clear(Calendar.SECOND);
  gc2.clear(Calendar.MINUTE);
  gc2.clear(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
  while ( gc1.before(gc2) ) {
     gc1.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
     elapsed++;
  }
  return elapsed;
```

}

That would return you the difference in the number of days.