# dont get expected result using method `compareTo()` and `equals()`

Tags: android, date, equals, compareto

I need to compare two dates.
which I read one of them from my database that its type is `String`. so first i convert `String` to `Date` in the specific format that i need, then I get the second `Date` from system again in the format that I want.
my problem is even when they are same i get unexpected result.

my code is:

```
public class SaharDateComparerActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sahar_date_comparer);
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    String dateString ="18/02/2015";


    Date datee = convertStringToDate(dateString);
    Log.i("SAHAR","date 1:  "+ dateFormat.format(datee).toString());


    Date myDate = new Date();
    Log.i("SAHAR", "date 2:  "+dateFormat.format(myDate).toString());

    int testttt=    datee.compareTo(myDate);
    boolean a = datee.toString().equals(myDate.toString());
    Log.i("SAHAR", "date compared:  "+String.valueOf(testttt));
    Log.i("SAHAR", "date equal:  "+String.valueOf(a));

}

public Date convertStringToDate(String strDate) {
    // String startDateString = "06/27/2007";
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    Date date = null;
    try {
        date = df.parse(strDate);
        String newDateString = df.format(date);
        System.out.println(newDateString);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return date;
 }
}
```

[image: and what i get is this]

as you can see my two dates are same but i get -1 when i use `compareTo()` and `false` when i use `equals()` method!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should compare your `Date` objects after clearing the time units missing in the date coming from the database i.e. without hours, minutes, seconds etc. This is what is affecting your results.

```
String dateString ="18/02/2015";
Date datee = convertStringToDate(dateString);

Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
c.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

Log.i("SAHAR", "Comparison result: " + datee.equals(c.getTime()));
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because the two dates have differnt hour,minutes,seconds,... (you don't see when you just do the toString() output)

You can remove them: [Compare two dates in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3144387/compare-two-dates-in-java)

Or you make your own Comperator where you just check the day/month/year.